# play a simple .wav on a view page?

Tags: android, audio, load, wav

In android, is there a way I can conditionally play a small .wav file when a layout is displayed to the user (on load), like so:

```
if (randonGen == 3) {
                //play small wav sound here        
                mTheMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
                mTheImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.face_image);
            mTheImageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(bitDraw);
            mThePicture.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
   }
```

Where the code to call my `sound.wav` from my assets folder is called and played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually - I figured out that a simple Media Play will do the trick with small wavs:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.your_wav);
            mp.start();
```

Comment: Useful to know.  I did see each View has playSoundEffect method but I didn't see a way of setting the sound to play so I presume that it probably just plays stock sounds.

Answer (score 1):

android.media.SoundPool looks like it will do what you want.